Number of Independent Components of a totally symmetric rank-four tensor
I saw a question that asked to derive the number of independent components of a rank-four tensor in d dimensions. I know the formula $\frac{(d+r-1)!}{(d-1)!(r!)}$, where d is the number of dimensions and r is the rank. I was trying a different approach for the same.
First, consider the case where all indices are the same. We have N such components. Then, consider the case where only two are the same, and the other two are different from this repeated index and among themselves (i.e., of the form $T^{aabc}$): Here, there are $N$ ways to choose the repeated index, $(N-1)$ to chose the index b, $(N-2)$ ways to chose the index c. Since the tensor is symmetric, to avoid overcounting of b and c, we divide by 2:
thus, the total number of components here is $\frac{N(N-1)(N-2)}{2}$: Now, consider the case where 3 indices are the same: here, the number $N(N-1)$. Finally, when all four indices are different, the number of independent components are ${^N}C_{4}$. Thus, the total number of independent components = $N+N(N-1)+\frac{N(N-1)(N-3)}{2}+ {^N}C_{4}$. But plugging in $N=4$ gives 29, whereas it should be 35, from the formula in the 1st paragraph. What is the flaw in the above arguments?

You missed the case where there are two pairs of equal indices ($aabb$). There are $\frac{N(N-1)}{2}$ of these, for $N=4$ this is $6$, exactly how much you undercounted.
